# In my Angular 6 Project I have put GOjs library it is giving TS compile errors

Tags: javascript, angular, gojs

I have just included the Gojs in my current angular project.

The steps I have followed

```
npm install gojs --save
```

and in my app component, i just imported gojs

```
import * as go from 'gojs';
```

after that when i run ng serve/build i am getting below errors.

```
RROR in node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14239,27): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14239,45): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14239,68): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14240,16): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14240,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14241,43): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14242,5): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14242,7): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14242,11): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14242,12): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/gojs/release/go.d.ts(14242,14):
```

#### `Pacakage.json`

```
"@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.0.2",
"@angular/language-service": "~6.0.2",

"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.2.1",

"gulp": "^4.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^3.1.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
"minimist": "~1.2.0",
"ng-packagr": "~3.0.0-rc.2",
"protractor": "^5.4.1",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tsickle": ">=0.25.5",
"tslib": "~1.7.1",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "^2.7.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @walter Northwoods,

I just downgraded GOJS 2.* to 1.8*

```
npm install gojs@1.8.34
```

Resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your TypeScript version.
The go.d.ts file requires v2.8.
To upgrade your current TypeScript Verison do: `npm install -g typescript@latest`.

Comment: Angular has a _specific TypeScript version_ dependency, be careful to just upgrade TypeScript without considering side-effects. Possibly better to upgrade Angular, which can be done with `ng upgrade` usually fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks for the warning,
Can you tell me more about ng upgrade and how it works?

Comment: I cannot upgrade angular as it has lot of other dependencies. Is there any other way??

Comment: Use v1.8.* of GoJS, rather than v2.0.* of GoJS.

Comment: @OfirLana Sure! The Angular CLI (which has a command-line binary called [`ng update`](https://angular.io/cli/update)) will do much of the upgrade process for you. For example, when RxJS moved to the `pipe()` paradigm, it rewrote my services from chained `http.get().map()` to `http.get().pipe(map())`. As well as managing dependencies and so on.

Comment: @Overflowrun I would _strongly_ suggest you try [`ng update`](https://angular.io/cli/update) and just see if it works. You don't necessarily need to update your other dependencies. Also what Walter said. I'm running a huge application with some deps that are fozen for compatibility reasons, but I could still upgrade most of angular around them.

Comment: @msanford ng-update is not a better option for me i have couple of things in the project that needs to be taken care if i do that.

Comment: @Overflowrun Ok, just thought I'd share my experience. :) Glad downgrading solved your issue, I'm very interested in gojs myself!